# What is a good mathematically inclined book for a Lisp beginner?

Tags: math, lisp

I am looking for a mathematical book on Lisp. Some ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematical book"?  A book using Lisp to solve math problems or a book on lisp that is mathematically rigorous?

Comment: I enjoy both of them. The question is therefore open.

Comment: You should read the source code to Maxima, a CAS written in CL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs uses mathematical examples. It's not really a book for learning a particular version of Lisp, but you'll learn the concepts.

Comment: Are there any actual proofs in this book?

Answer (score 3):

[Essentials of Programming Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262062178)

Answer (score 3):

- [*Elegant LISP Programs*](http://www.cs.umaine.edu/~chaitin/lisp.html) by G. J. Chaitin
- [*Maxima by Example*](http://www.csulb.edu/~woollett/) by Edwin L. Woollett Web Page

However, please be noted that Chaitin's version of `LISP' is not the common Lisp used by programmers nowadays to do more practical things.  For the more practical aspects of Lisp programming, see [*Practical Common Lisp*](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) by Peter Seibel.

Answer (score 2):

John Allen's [Anatomy of Lisp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007001115X).